# Accessing a very particular address in Python using socket module

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to access the following page using only the socket program:

"https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Category:Arabic_lemmas&from=%D8%B1"

Heres is my current code:

```
import socket

URL_HANDLE = "en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Category:Arabic_lemmas&from="
SAMPLE_URL = "en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Category:Arabic_lemmas&from=ر"
URL = "www.wiktionary.org"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect((SAMPLE_URL, 80))
payload = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {}\r\n\r\n".format(SAMPLE_URL)
s.sendall(payload.encode())
print(s.recv(4096))
s.close
```

Doing just URL by itself is fine, but the others are not. I noticed that URL worked only when I got rid of the trailing "https://" at the beginning. But when I try SAMPLE_URL I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/matth/PycharmProjects/ArabProject/wiktsearcher.py", line 9, in <module>
    s.connect((SAMPLE_URL, 80))
TypeError: encoding of hostname failed
```

What is so wacky about the URL I'm trying to access, that Python can't resolve it? Is there a way around it?

Comment: In short: `connect` expects an IP address or hostname. A URL is none of this.

Comment: This is a fairly important thing to understand.  Your network consists of a stack of handlers, each one handling one particular part.  The socket only cares about the domain and the port.  The domain is "en.wiktionary.org".  The port for "https" is 443 (NOT 80).  Once you've made that connection, HTTP doesn't care about the domain or the port. 
 You do a GET for "/w/index.php?title-Category:Arabic_lemmas&from=".  Packages like "requests" take care of this for you.